# REACT NATIVE + FIREBASE: running app in cellphone throws "Error: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Im new to react native, currently building a project with firebase to learn the basics. I used expo to create the project.

While running the project with expo in web browser, everything works just fine, but when i run the app with expo on my android device (moto g30) trying to log an user throws this "Error: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."

This is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";
import firebase from "firebase";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const onSignIn = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="email"
        required
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="password"
        required
        value={password}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <Button title="LOG" onPress={onSignIn} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to initialise the firebase app and import "firebase/auth"

Comment: Oh, i did it in the main component. The weird part its that it runs just fine in web browser.

Comment: Try changing the `onChange(()=>{}` to `onChangeText((val)=> setEmail(val))`

Comment: It actually solved the problem! TY